# Using libcurl to fetch records from redis data structure as database based on keywords.

Tags: redis, libcurl

I have an application where in I crawl a website, scrape it's contents & store it in Redis data structure as a database in  form. I am using Html tidy for converting website in Xml. Then parsing of the xml document by RapidXml & data binding is done by Code synthesis XSD. I am using C++ language for this module.
    My question is, **how do I use libcurl to fetch records based on keywords from redis ?**
Any help would be highly appreciated, if not the code any links or any direction is also extremely valuable. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use C++, you can use the hiredis C [redis client](http://redis.io/clients).

If you really want to use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), [here](http://redis.io/topics/protocol) is the Redis protocol explained. If you don't want to use the Redis protocol directly, use a RESTful interface like [RestMQ](http://restmq.com/) or [Webdis](http://webd.is/)

Hope this helps, TW